# Use a custom controller class with Ardalis.ApiEndpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, endpoint

I'm using the `EndpointBaseAsync` extension throughout an asp.net core API project. I want to have a custom ("CurrentUser") object on all my endpoints (controllers) that's populated by middleware/a filter.

I can't see how to implement this in e.g. a custom controller class, that I can then use as the base for EndpointBase. The issue is probably my knowledge rather than any technical issue. For now, instead I've resorted to not having a custom controller class, and instead adding my custom object to `HttpContext.Items` in middleware.

Then in my endpoint I need to do this:

`var user = (User)HttpContext.Items["CurrentUser"];`

Instead I just want it all done and have available a custom `CurrentUser` that I can use straight away without that ugly assignment.

Without messing around with the source for Ardalis.ApiEndpoints, how can I expose all the goodness of that library but with a custom underlying controller base class?